# how to store values from android webview and make a sql query?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-webview

I have a android webview which makes user registration: first the user enters his email id and phone number and after submission the user has to enter the 4 digit pin sent to the email. Now the problem is every time user has to verify when he opens the app. I am finding a solution in which when the user submits the email address, that email is stored in the android app and when the user opens the app next time it checks from the database using a sql query to the database if the user is verified webview will redirect to another page. how to achieve this ?

Comment: Use Firebase RealTime Database  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: I have checked the link but did not found it helpful can you please explain how can i use it?

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-example-android-application/

Comment: The subject of your post does not match the text of your post. Confusing.